# what is the use of the following for loop while adding data to the hash table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashtable

```
for i in range(len(hashBucket)):
        if hashBucket[i][0] == dictKey:
            hashBucket[i] = (dictKey, dictVal)
```

implementing dictionaries using hashing.
this is the full code:

```
class intDict(object):
"""A dictionary with integer keys"""

def __init__(self, numBuckets):
    """Create an empty dictionary"""
    self.buckets = []
    self.numBuckets = numBuckets
    for i in range(numBuckets):
        self.buckets.append([])
```

## HERE

```
def addEntry(self, dictKey, dictVal):
    """Assumes dictKey an int. Adds an entry."""
    hashBucket = self.buckets[dictKey%self.numBuckets]
    for i in range(len(hashBucket)):
        if hashBucket[i][0] == dictKey:
            hashBucket[i] = (dictKey, dictVal)
    hashBucket.append((dictKey, dictVal))

def getValue(self, dictKey):
    """Assumes dictKey an int. Returns entry associated
       with the key dictKey"""
    hashBucket = self.buckets[dictKey%self.numBuckets]
    for e in hashBucket:
        if e[0] == dictKey:
            return e[1]
    return None

def __str__(self):
    result = '{'
    for b in self.buckets:
        for e in b:
            result = result + str(e[0]) + ':' + str(e[1]) + ','
    return result[:-1] + '}' 
import random

D = intDict(10)
for  i in range(20):
  key = random.choice(range(100))
  D.addEntry(key, i)     

print("the value of the intDict")
print(D)

for hashBucket in D.buckets:
    print(' ', hashBucket)
```

Even after removing the for loop i got similar results.
I saw this code in the book "introduction to computation and programming using python".

Answer (score 0):

Hashmaps are an optmization of just keeping key-value pairs in a big list.  They divide the list into smaller lists so that fewer items need examined to see if you have a match or not when doing lookups or insertions.

Once the correct hashbucket is found, the code you are asking about examines each entry IN THAT BUCKET to see if they key matches, and if so, returns the value.

The key, pun intended,  is to have enough buxkets that they are small enough to quickly scan, but not so many that you use up too much memory.